# How can I address individual outputs of a neural network from a custom Tensorflow loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I'd like to implement a custom loss function (specifically [for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206942/how-can-i-predict-the-expected-value-and-the-variance-simultaneously-with-a-neur)) for training a NN in Tensorflow, in which NN has two outputs, and the loss function is a formula involving both outputs and the expected output. How can I individually adress those? [Examples from tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py) it looks e.g. like:

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred):
  y_pred = ops.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
  y_true = math_ops.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
  diff = math_ops.abs(
      (y_true - y_pred) / K.clip(math_ops.abs(y_true), K.epsilon(), None))
  return 100. * K.mean(diff, axis=-1)
```

What exactly are the tensors passed in here as y_true - what shape do they have? I haven't been able to find any documentation about that. All the examples I've seen for custom losses just calculate all outputs at once, whereas I need to pick out individual outputs.

Please note: I cannot define the network into two outputs and define a separate loss for each output, as the [Model.compile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model#compile) documentation allows / as it [is done here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44929112/21499), since the loss function is a function of all three values.

Comment: Compute the loss, involving two outputs, as a tensor and then add it to the model using `model.add_loss(...)`. The `loss` argument you specify in `compile` method is applied on each output separately, so it's no use in your case.

Comment: @today Thank you! Could you perhaps point me to an example for that? I'm still a newbie to Tensorflow right now. :-)

Comment: This [official Keras example on VAE](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/9d33a024e3893ec2a4a15601261f44725c6715d1/examples/variational_autoencoder.py#L187) might be helpful to get an idea. As you can see there is no `loss` argument specified in `compile` method. Clearly it depends on the architecture of your model, so you may need to adapt it according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find documentation about the shape of the parameters y_pred and y_true, but the following seems to work: to access individual outputs (assuming the output is onedimensional) you can slice on the last axis of the tensor: e.g. `y_pred[..., 0:1]` is the first output, `y_pred[..., 1::2]` is every odd numbered output, `y_true[..., 0::2]` every even numbered label and so forth.